# Why there is no GPS updates

Tags: android, gps

I used example from [here](http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/), run it on my Galaxy Tab but have no changes for 20 minutes.. Where can the problem be?

Comment: try this example http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/map-api-in-android.html

Comment: Did you check if any other GPS app from the market can get a location? If they can't, then you've got a gps signal reception problem, or gps is off/broken on your Tab. If they work, and the example doesn't, then the example's broken

Comment: Google maps native application works perfect

Comment: Can you get at least one fix ?

Comment: GPS enabled and the icon is working on top panel

Comment: GPS reception will be quite weak indoors. When I was developing a GPS test app for the tablet, I remember running to the window every time to get a quick fix. I suggest you to check for the signal strength near the windows where you can get a clear view of the sky. It really helps! Also it would be great if you can post the GpsLocationProvider logs of Android LBS Framework along with the GPS HAL layer logs, if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you example, the location updates are requested this way :

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, this);
```

**First**, this only uses the GPS **location provider**, whereas Google Maps uses any available location sensor (GPS, Wifi, etc.). In order to use the GPS, you must be able to receive the signal from the satellites, so place your device next to a window or even better, outside.

In the status bar, the dish icon flashes intermittently when searching and continuously when it has a fix. You can check more precisely the status of the GPS fix on your phone with an app like this one : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eclipsim.gpsstatus2

**Second**, the `10f` value for the **`minDistance` parameter** tells the system to only give you updates when the location has moved more than 10 meters ; so if the GPS thinks you stay within a 10m radius of your first location fix, it will not bother you with new positions.

Comment: ok.. I checked some apps which use GPS and found that they are don't work too. Can this be caused by night time of day?

Comment: no, GPS works all the time... What does the GPS status app says? You can also try to replace LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER by LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER in your code (less accurate, but faster and more available - internet connection needed)

Comment: internet (the device has to send a request to the Google servers), but turn on your wifi (no need to connect it to an AP) to get better results.